# ¿Se pueden "automatizar" los <meta> y <title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title> con php? ¿no causa efectos o problemas para el usuario?

Tags: php, html5, meta-tags

Así es como quiero poner mi código (viene de Mysql a php):

```html
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $titulo1; ?>"/>   
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $titulo2; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $titulo3; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $titulo4; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:description” content=”<?php echo $titulo5; ?>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="e<?php echo $css1; ?>">
```

Comment: No hay ningun problema mientras genera contenido en el formato adecuado (por ejemplo, aplicando `htmlspecialchars()` a los valores, especialmente descripciones). Ya que la info se genera en el backend, para el cliente no hay diferencia si el resultado es el mismo

Comment: OJO, si `$titulo1` y demás variables cambian (me refiero a que hoy `$titulo1` vale una cosa y la semana próxima vale otra) estarías incurriendo en una mala práctica desde el punto de vista de SEO. El título, descripción y otros metadatos de una página no deberían cambiar constantemente.

Comment: Ten en cuenta la recomendación de @A.Cedano así: los datos con mucha variabilidad no deben ir a metadatos dado que éstos tienen propósito de indexación y clasificación de contenidos para facilitar su búsqueda y recuperación.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Lo estoy haciendo de esta forma, porque serán "muchas paginas", paginas que creará un usuario, pero que nunca cambiaran las variables, cada subdominio siempre recibirá la misma variable. Muchísimas Gracias

Comment: @Abner *«cada subdominio siempre recibirá la misma variable»* ... Deberías tener cuidado también con eso. Si tienes metadatos duplicados (varias páginas con el mismo `title, description`, etc, igualmente tus dominios serán penalizados a nivel de SEO. Todos estos aspectos deben considerarse si quieres que tus páginas tengan una posición de respeto en los buscadores. Cuando una página es penalizada a nivel de SEO significa que pasa a un lugar inferior en los buscadores, de modo que cuando alguien busca sobre la temática de tu página la misma aparecerá en la posición `99999` en vez de ...

Comment: ... en la posición `1` o en la posición `10` o en la posición `17`. Tu página será entonces irrelevante y nadie la encontrará. Hay varias reglas de SEO que conviene conocer al momento de crear metadatos de las páginas de un dominio.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por la información! pero cada usuario tendrá diferente nombre al crearse, cada subdominio. Me equivoque al decir que la misma variable, es, el mismo nombre de variable, pero le llegara diferente información. lo que quiero es: Crear una nueva pagina insertando esos valores en mysql. ¡Mil gracias!